# How do I convert this to html element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a function that highlights words in a sentence. Here is the code for that.

```
highlightText = () => {
        const {
            questionItem,
        } = this.props;
        const words = questionItem.split(/\s+/);
        const highlighted = words.map((word, index) => (
            <span key={index} className="highlighted-word">{word}</span>
        ));
        const text = highlighted.join(' ');
        console.log(text);
        console.log({ highlighted });
        return highlighted;
    }
```

here if I console the "text" I get [Object object] so instead i'm returning "highlighted" and then joining it using reduce.

```
        const text3 = <p>{this.highlightText().reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ' ', curr])}</p>;
```

and I want to use this "text3" in a component. The problem is I'm getting the "text3" as
[image]

I want it to be a HTML element so that I can use it in my component. How can I convert it?
Also if I directly display `<p>{this.highlightText().reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ' ', curr])}</p>` in my webpage instead of using it in my component it's working fine.

Comment: Just use `<text3/>` inside your existing react component.

Comment: You cannot just `.join(' ')` an array of jsx elements; they are not strings (and the implicit conversion to strings turns them into `'[object Object]'`). What you need instead is to map the returned array into the DOM adding whitespace on the fly: `<p>{this.highlightText().map((word,i) => (i === 0) ? <>{word}</> : <> {word}</>)}</p>` or intersperse whitespace with a reduce `<p>{this.highlightText().reduce((prev, curr, i) => (i===0) ? [curr] : [...prev, ' ', curr], [])}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new component which take `props`. Try this...

```
export default function HighlightText({text}) {
 return <span className="Add_HighlightText_Class" >{text}</span>
```